# Persisted Spark RDD not available in another Spark shell

Tags: apache-spark, persist, rdd

We have a Spark-1.1.0 standalone 2-node cluster on which a Spark RDD has been created using a Spark shell. The RDD has been persisted (MEMORY_ONLY). I am unable to retrieve this RDD from another Spark shell using sc.getPersistentRDDs(). Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RDDs are persisted within the context of the `SparkContext` that originated that RDD and are only accesible through the Spark Context that created them.

This means that you cannot access an RDD created with a SparkContext from another SparkContext B as would be the case with a second Spark-shell.

Comment: Thanks. But then does it mean that there is no way to share a generated and persisted RDD for future use? This seems a little anti to Spark's principle of iterative processing.

Comment: Iterative process relates to algorithms that need to go over the same dataset multiple times, making some computations each time and potentially transforming it. If you want to re-use the result of a computation for 'future use', you can always persist the RDD to disk. You could also look into [Tachyon](http://tachyon-project.org/) for an in-memory alternative.

Comment: Thank you maasg, that clarifies. I misinterpreted the meaning of persist.